# Why do we use $\left<\varphi,x\right>$ for $\varphi(x)$ when $\varphi$ is a linear functional?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

Let $V$ a $K-$vector space and $V^*$ it's dual. What is the motivation of using the notation $\left<\varphi,x\right>$ for $\varphi(x)$ ? Is it a consequence of the fact that \begin{align*}
\left<\cdot ,\cdot \right>: V^*\times V&\longrightarrow K\\ (\varphi,x)&\longmapsto \left<\varphi,x\right>=:\varphi(x)
\end{align*}

would be a scalar product ? But it looks strange since a scalar product must take element form $V\times V$ or $V^*\times V^*$, but not of the form $V^*\times V$.

Comment: It is an example of a more general concept of a "bilinear function" on two $K$-vector spaces, meaning a function $W \times V \to K$, often denoted $(w,v) \mapsto \langle w, v \rangle$, defined by certain properties. In brief, it respects addition and scalar multiplication in each variable separately, for example $\langle w_1 + w_2 , v \rangle = \langle w_1,v \rangle + \langle w_2,v \rangle$.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that any linear functional can be expressed as an inner product is true only if the vector space $V$ is a Hilbert space.

This is the content of the [Riesz Representation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem).

In this case a linear functional $\varphi(y)$ can be identified with the inner product of a vector $x$ with $y$ so that we can write $\varphi(y)=\langle x,y\rangle$. The functional $\varphi$  and the vector $x$ are dual and , with an abuse of notation, we use the same symbol to indicate both them, so we can write $\varphi(y)=\langle \varphi, y\rangle$, but really the second $\varphi$ is an element of the hilbert space  and the first is the the corresponding element (by Riesz Theorem) in the dual space.

Answer (score 1):

For any linear functional $\varphi$, there exists a vector $v$ such that $\varphi(x) = \langle v,x \rangle$ for all $x$. This is actually a one-to-one correspondence between $V^{*}$ and $V$. Thus it makes practical sense to represent a linear functional $\varphi$ as an element of $V$, with the convention that $\varphi(x) = \langle \varphi,x \rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

When $V $  is a Hilbert space (a very common situation, for instance in physics), you have  $V^*=V $, so it is an actual inner product.

Answer (score 0):

As Lee Mosher wrote in a comment, the brackets $\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle$ are very common for *bilinear maps*.
These are maps $V\times W \to \mathbb{R}$, where $V$ and $W$ are real vector spaces, such that
$$
\langle ax+by,z\rangle = a\langle x,z\rangle + b\langle y,z\rangle \quad\text{for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x,y\in V$ and $z\in W$} \\
\langle x,ay+bz\rangle = a\langle x,y\rangle + b\langle x,z\rangle \quad\text{for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x\in V$ and $y,z\in W$.} $$
The notation for linear functionals is a special case where $W = V^*$.
(I wrote it here for vector spaces over the real numbers, but this works equally well for vector spaces over other fields, or even modules over rings.)

As to *why* this notation is used, I can't be sure. However, from experience I can say that it is often convenient to have a notation that looks more symmetric than function application, when you have two spaces that are dual to each other, but it is not clear which one should be $V$ and which one should be $V^*$ (after all, $(V^*)^*$ is just $V$ -- at least for sufficently nice spaces).

**Note:** In quantum mechanics, there is a very similar notation called [Bra-ket notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation). If you want to name your quantum state $\psi$, you write it $\mid \psi \rangle$. If you want to name an element of the dual space $\phi$, you write it $\langle \phi \mid$. The evaluation of $\phi$ as $\psi$ is then written $\langle \phi \mid \psi\rangle$. It was introduced by Paul Dirac in 1939 in *[A new notation for quantum mechanics](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=2031476)*.